# Nullable(Of ) : type of parameter for <Attribute>. Does it work?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, attributes

I'm trying to use the type Boolean for some  parameter.

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited:=True, AllowMultiple:=False)>
Public Class MyAttribute
             Inherits Attribute
  Property MyCondition As Boolean
End Class
```

I'm facing the problem that, in my object *MyAttribute*, I'm not able to say if the boolean property has the value False:

- because of the presence of the parameter (e: MyCondition:=false)

or,

- because no parameter was passed and my property has the value False because of the initialization of my object.

I though about using a property Nullable(Of Boolean) instead, but this doesn't seem to be allowed?

```
Property MyCondition As Nullable(of Boolean)
```

**Error message** "*Property or field 'MyCondition' does not have a valid attribute type*."

Is there a walk-around this situation? Is the only workable parameter type is String (that is null on instantiation) ?

Comment: Are you saying that you need to be able to tell which way was used to set it to false?  That it is definitely false, but you need to know why?  What doesn't work about it if you make it nullable?

Comment: @SteveDog : Yes I want to be able to determine if this property has been set or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you can only use simple data types that can be represented as a literal constant in code (e.g. 100, True, "Test").  That is probably why Nullable(Of Boolean) is not working for you.  You can, however, accomplish what you are trying to do by creating actual property handlers:

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited:=True, AllowMultiple:=False)>
Public Class MyAttribute
    Inherits Attribute

    Public Property MyCondition As Boolean
        Get
            Return _myCondition
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _myCondition = value
            _explicitlySet = True
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _myCondition As Boolean = False

    Public ReadOnly Property ExplicitlySet As Boolean
        Get
            Return _explicitlySet
        End Get
    End Property
    Private _explicitlySet As Boolean = False
End Class
```

Alternatively, you could make it a read-only nullable property and use a constructor to set it:

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited:=True, AllowMultiple:=False)>
Public Class MyAttribute
    Inherits Attribute

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(myCondition As Boolean)
        _myCondition = myCondition
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property MyCondition As Nullable(Of Boolean)
        Get
            Return _myCondition
        End Get
    End Property
    Private _myCondition As Nullable(Of Boolean)
End Class
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about this, but I was wondering if it's not overkill... And in fact I want to compare 2 attributes to see if they match, using Equals. This won't help I think.

Comment: Hmmm, I think that non optional parameter can be a way to go. Give me 10 min to consider it...

Answer (score 0):

Use an enumeration instead

```
public enum TriState
{
    NotSet,
    False,
    True
}
```

Comment: I also though about this, but, I could explain that same problem with Integer type parameters. 0 by setting or instantiation? I won't be able to create an enum with all the values of an Integer, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a three class approach

```
MyAttribute (inherits Attribute)
ValidMyAttribute (interits MyAttribute)
InvalidMyAttribute (inherits MyAttribute)

' means true
<ValidMyAttribute> _
Public Sub MyMethod1()

' means false
<InvalidMyAttribute> _
Public Sub MyMethod2()

' means not defined
<MyAttribute> _
Public Sub MyMethod3()
```

the classes should look like this

```
Public class MyAttribute
    Inherits Attribute

    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Value as Boolean?
        Get
            return nothing
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Public class ValidMyAttribute
    Inherits MyAttribute

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Value as Boolean?
        Get
            return true
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Public class ValidMyAttribute
    Inherits MyAttribute

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Value as Boolean?
        Get
            return false
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

**Update:**

Just had a second thought and this should be much easier:

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited:=True, AllowMultiple:=False)>
Public Class MyAttribute
    Inherits Attribute
    Public Property Value As Boolean? = Nothing
    Public Sub New(value As Boolean)
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Usage:

```
<MyAttribute(True)> _
Public Sub Method()

<MyAttribute(false)> _
Public Sub Method()

' Value will be nothing
<MyAttribute()> _
Public Sub Method()
```